# Redshift Staging Bucket name in IICS

Tags: amazon-redshift, iics

I have a Redshift Database Instance which i am using in Informatica to load some data. How can i find the S3 bucket name for this Redshift Instance?
I am using AmazonRedshift connector and I need to provide the S3 bucket name in my Informatica Job.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Redshift databases don't have one single nominated S3 bucket. Instead you need to choose an existing S3 bucket that your Redshift cluster has been granted access to.

It's easiest to choose an S3 bucket in the same AWS account. Create one if necessary. That bucket will get used in the [COPY command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html)

You also need to give Redshift permission to use that S3 bucket. AWS prefer that you do this by setting up an IAM role that has the required S3 permissions - which are basically listing the bucket and getting objects. Attach the IAM role to your Redshift cluster in the "properties" settings in your AWS console. More details on the exact permissions required are in the [Redshift Database Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-access-permissions.html#copy-usage_notes-iam-permissions).